# Tkinter buttons with images not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, button

So, i was trying to make a music player with python and tkinter and I had to set images for the buttons, but when I set an image for the button, the button does not appear on the output screen

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
win = Tk()
win.title("Music player")
win.geometry("500x300")

# Images for buttons
back_png = PhotoImage("C:/1 Files and Folders/SHARAN/Python/SVE atom/Images/back.png")
back_button = Button(win, image=back_png, borderwidth=0).place(x=100, y=20)


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

tkinter requires a keyword for most arguments. Here you are missing the `file=` keyword.

```
back_png = PhotoImage(file="C:/1 Files and Folders/SHARAN/Python/SVE atom/Images/back.png")
```

Comment: Hmm works for me ... I tested it. Still same problem? Are you getting an error? Describe what the problem is.

Comment: No error, the output screen appears but with no button, or with a extremely tiny button

Comment: Hey, I was able to fix, it wasn't a problem with my code, my IDE was ignoring PhotoImages